# CSS Sticky Footer when content does not take up entire page

Tags: html, css

I have two pages that differ only by the content contained in the **content-box** div tag.  You can see them here:

[Tall Version](http://embeddedanalytics.com/eatall.htm)

[Short Version](http://embeddedanalytics.com/eashort.htm)

I have included the html/css code for the **short** version below.  I would like to have the **short** version display so that if the amount of content does not fill up the entire page, the footer will still stick to the bottom AND the entire area between the header and the footer in the middle of the screen is the white corresponding to the **content-box** div.

What do I need to change to accomplish this?\

**Update 1** I made a new page doing what @smallworld suggested.  It can be seen [here](http://embeddedanalytics.com/eashort1.html).  This has a sticky footer, but I would like the outside "container" box to extend the height of the page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
            "text/html; charset=us-ascii">
            <style type="text/css">


                #main {
                    width: 100%;
                    min-height: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }

                body {
                    width: 100%;
                }


                #header,#content { position:relative; right:0;left:0}

                #header{
                    height:75px; top:0;
                    background: #4396CA;
                }
                #footer{
                    width: 100%;
                    position: relative;
                    height:50px;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    background: #4396CA;
                }
                #content{
                    top:00px;
                    background: #F0F8FF;
                    min-height: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }

                #content-box {
                    width: 950px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    background-color: #FFFFFF;
                    text-align: left;
                    border-right: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
                    border-left: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
                    padding-bottom: 20px;
                    padding-top: 20px;
                    min-height: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }

            </style>
            <title>EmbeddedAnalytics - Test Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="header">this is header</div>
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="content-box">
                        <b>Content does not take up all of box.  But still want footer to "stick" to bottom</b><br>
                        line1<br>
                        line2<br>
                        line3<br>
                      Last Line<br></div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">footer</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: [Is that what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341415/content-container-to-fit-screensize/12342330#12342330) ?

Comment: Yes - I have searched "sticky footer", but obviously not doing something properly.

Comment: Here is a page that I based it off of: http://www.pud.ca/misc/testcase/fullheight.html  I think what makes this a bit more complicated is the "content-box" within the "content".  Most of the sticky examples I have seen are basic in the sense there are three blocks only: header, content, footer.

Comment: Your code is nothing like that fullheight.html example. In their example, body and html have `height: 100%`, footer is positioned absolutely, etc. Try following one of these examples and if you hit a snag come ask for help.

Comment: Yeah - I started with the fullheight.html example.  But I had to fork it because my page has nested containers.  So it is different.  See **Update 1**

Comment: Imo this http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ is the best and easiest to implement sticky footer. If it isnt working, it is for 1 very simple reason: you did not close your tags properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: See jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/smallworld/gcpNh/ - I have used class="xyz" instead of using id="xyz" in your example. I know that stretching to 100% height shouldn't be as difficult and stressful, but in reality, it is. I feel your pain and that's why trying to help as much as I can. I made one more correction - it should have been padding-bottom, not margin-bottom on "main" class.

CSS:

```
html {  height:100%;min-height:100% !important;margin:0;padding:0;   /** see height, min-height values here. **/ }
body{  overflow:auto;padding:0;margin:0;height:100%;min-height:100% !important;   /** see height, min-height values here. **/ }
.main { 
  position:relative;min-height:100%; height:auto; background:cyan;   
  /** see position, height, min-height values here. Height auto to make sure 
      that main div resizes if window size changes after initial rendering **/ 
}
.header { display:block;height:50px;position:relative;background:yellow;text-align:center;padding:10px; }
.content { padding:20px;margin-bottom:50px; /** bottom margin here to make sure that footer does not cover the content area **/  }
.footer { display:block;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;height:50px;background:red;color:white;text-align:center;padding:10px;  /** see position, top, left, and width properties here. **/  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="main clearfix">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="clearfix content">
        <h1>Goal of this fiddle is to demonstrate sticky footer implementation</h1>
        And domonstrate this with least amount of CSS and HTML, without using any extraordinary hacks. 
        <p>Your content goes in here. Add lot more content, and resize browser window to several different sizes to see how your page is rendered as compared to with very little content.</p>
    </div>        
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MSchenkel - NO, you haven't made the changes suggested. Check your DOCTYPE, there is no height, min-height specified on the body element. You need to read and implement ALL suggested bullets (it's as short and sweet as it gets). Seriously, if you need help, PLEASE put in some serious efforts. Otherwise, I won't (unless I see absolutely no effort before asking questions) but many others here will down vote your question.

Comment: sorry about that.  Didn't think the DOCTYPE would have a difference (and it didn't).  I modified the body tag to have the height and min-height.  Otherwise the other changes have been made.  Now look at http://embeddedanalytics.com/eashort1.html - I would like have the outside light blue container stretch the entire length of the page.  Trust me - I have put a lot of effort in this.  What makes it difficult is that I had to change the other examples to accommodate a nested container box.

Comment: @MSchenkel I completely changed my answer with code and a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: I think this is it.  So what I really wanted was a box nested in a box like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bhbu7/4/  I will try it on my site.

Comment: @MSchenkel Don't forget to "Accept" this as an answer if it meets your needs. I organize a large web design meetup group (~900 members) and I can't remember any other CSS issue that developers have struggled with more than this. There are lot of examples out there most of them are not simple and concise so I thought... hack, I will put together this fiddle for you and share with anyone asking me about sticky footer next time - a one time investment. I am glad it seems to be what you were looking for.

Comment: Sorry it has taken so long to respond.  I immediately tried your solution but still came across some issues.  I have the sticky part working.  But additionally what I would like added is a center white area.  If you took your fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/smallworld/gcpNh/ ), is there a way to make a center white area which stretches the length of the cyan area?  See this page for more: http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/eashort2.html

Comment: add top: 100%; to .footer for the icing on the cake.