# Sticky footer when content is shorter than page size

Tags: html, css

I've got a footer that works fine, but when the size of content in the page is shorter than the page size, the footer is rendered below the content not in the bottom of the page, here is an image:

[image]

Here is my code (jsbin snippet):

```css
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-color: #2D2D2D;
      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
     }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


    </head>
    <body ng-app="AngularJSApp">
    <div class="contentBody">
         
        
        <div id="contenido"> 
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="footer">
       
        <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2015 Diego Unanue &mdash; <a href="http://ryanfait.com/" title="3xM Web Design">3xM Web Design</a></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to fix this problem, and always keep the footer in the bottom of the page?

Comment: `position: fixed; bottom: 0`

Comment: @gp. How would you know when to have it fixed and not? I'm sure he doesn't want the footer fixed the whole time.

Comment: it would be better if you could provide us your code on jsFiddle..

Comment: @user26409021 I'll add a snippet

Comment: position: fixed; bottom: 0 makes the footer floats over the content, hiding a part of the content

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol) - look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8825714/2365792)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Sticky Footer when content does not take up entire page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827100/css-sticky-footer-when-content-does-not-take-up-entire-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this sticky footer:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.contentBody {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -100px
}
.contentBody:after {
  content: "";
  display: block
}
.footer,
.contentBody:after {
  height: 100px
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2D2D2D;
  text-align: center;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="AngularJSApp">
  <div class="contentBody">
    <div id="contenido">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2015 Diego Unanue &mdash; <a href="http://ryanfait.com/" title="3xM Web Design">3xM Web Design</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
 }
```

and on .footer change

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```

to

```
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
html,body {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```